# Dynamic TSQL Date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to make Month pull the previous month Dynamically somehow so something like MONTH(bea_CreatedOn) - 1, so this report will automatically pull the month total columns correctly. So the Where bea_CreatedOn >= '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000' and bea_CreatedOn <= '2015-07-31 23:59:59.000' portion in the code below.

```
SELECT cdb_Account_ID                       AS AccountID,
       cdb_Database,
       ISNULL(TMonthly.MonthlyTotalSent, 0) AS [Monthly Emails],
       ISNULL(TYearly.YearlyTotalSent, 0)   AS [YTD Emails],
       '10000'                              AS Baseline,
       'Monthly'                            AS [Monthly vs Yearly],
       '.01'                                AS [Rate after Baseline],
       CASE
         WHEN ISNULL(TMonthly.MonthlyTotalSent, 0) < 10000
           THEN 0
         ELSE ( ISNULL(TMonthly.MonthlyTotalSent, 0) - 10000 ) * .01
       END                                  AS [Billable Amount],
       '360'                                AS Product,
       ''                                   AS [Paid -Y/N]
FROM   [HVV-CENTRALOPSDB].[Security].[dbo].[sec_ClientDatabase] AS t1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT bea_cdb_GUID,
                         SUM(bea_D_count)                    AS MonthlyDelivered,
                         SUM(bea_B_Count)                    AS MonthlyBounce,
                         SUM(bea_D_Count) + SUM(bea_B_count) AS MonthlyTotalSent
                  FROM   [HVV-CENTRALOPSDB].[CentralOps].[dbo].[cop_BlastEmailUsage]
                  WHERE  bea_CreatedOn >= '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000'
                         AND bea_CreatedOn <= '2015-07-31 23:59:59.000'
                  GROUP  BY bea_cdb_GUID) AS TMonthly
         ON tMonthly.bea_cdb_GUID = cdb_GUID
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT bea_cdb_GUID,
                         SUM(bea_D_count)                    AS YearlyDelivered,
                         SUM(bea_B_Count)                    AS YearlyBounce,
                         SUM(bea_D_Count) + SUM(bea_B_count) AS YearlyTotalSent
                  FROM   [HVV-CENTRALOPSDB].[CentralOps].[dbo].[cop_BlastEmailUsage]
                  WHERE  bea_CreatedOn >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                         AND bea_CreatedOn <= '2015-12-31 23:59:59.000'
                  GROUP  BY bea_cdb_GUID) AS TYearly
         ON tYearly.bea_cdb_GUID = cdb_GUID
WHERE  cdb_Deleted = 0
       AND ( ( cdb_Database NOT LIKE '%Test%'
                OR cdb_Database NOT LIKE '%Sample%'
                OR cdb_Database NOT LIKE '%VIQ%' )
              OR cdb_Database NOT IN ( 'P6_OLP_Impl_20091222', 'P6_OLP_LIBE_20101224', 'P7Test_Aristotle_1_11192013', 'P7Test_Aristotle_1_11202013',
                                       'P6_NA-DBName_20131009', 'P6_NAR_SANDBOX', 'P6_VIQ_ASAP_20140314', 'P6_VIQ_TechSupport_20140314',
                                       'P6_VIQ_BerlinRosen_20140314', 'P6_VIQ_Demo_20140314', '' ) )
       AND ISNULL(TYearly.YearlyTotalSent, 0) > 0
```

Comment: I am still not sure what's the question here though?

Comment: I need to make this query Dynamic in order for the Month to pull the previous month

Comment: Which version of Sql Server?

Comment: See [Writing The Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints).

Answer (score 0):

Your example had July dates but the month proceeding was August.

The following snippet will get you the proceeding start and end of month dates respectively. If you're using Sql Server 2012 then it can be simplified (hence my question).

```
Declare @StartDate DateTime = Cast(Floor(Cast(DateAdd(Month, -1, GetDate()) As Decimal(12, 5))) - ( Day(DateAdd(Month, -1, GetDate())) - 1 ) As DateTime);
Declare @EndDate DateTime = DateAdd(Month, 1, @StartDate) - 1;
```

NB, now you've said you're on 2012, take a look at the EOMonth function.

```
Declare @EndDate Date = EOMonth(DateAdd(Month, -1, GetDate();
Declare @StartDate Date = DateAdd(Day, 1, DateAdd(Month, -1, @EndDate));
```

Did this on my phone using the mobile app so haven't been able to check its all 100% perfect...

Comment: I see, and yes I am indeed using Sql Server 2012.

Comment: It's too late for me now to modify my answer. Not knowing which version you were on I gave you an all version response. I'll annotate with a quick note for a 2012+ possibility.